# xaml grid of grid verses tcl/tk grid of frames

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Here's my C# XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <Button x:Name="btnHome"      Content="Home"      Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnEnd"       Content="End"       Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button x:Name="btnRefresh"   Content="Refresh"   Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnSticky"    Content="Sticky"    Grid.Column="3"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnOpen"      Content="Open"      Grid.Column="4" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button  Grid.Column="0"   Content="clear"       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button  Grid.Column="1"   Content="search"       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2"   Text="adfasdfsdfasdf" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Azure"/>
        </Grid>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="2"  Background="Beige"/>
        <Label   Grid.Row="3"  Background="Azure" Margin="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and what it looks like:

[image]

Now Here's my TCL/TK attempting to do the same thing:

```
package require Tk

wm title . "MainWindow"
wm geometry . 200x450
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1

# Row 0
frame .row0
grid .row0 -row 0 -column 0 -columnspan 5 -sticky "ew"
grid columnconfigure .row0 {0 1 2 3 4} -weight 1
button .row0.b0c0 -text "Home";    grid .row0.b0c0 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "ew"
button .row0.b0c1 -text "End";     grid .row0.b0c1 -row 0 -column 1 -sticky "ew"
button .row0.b0c2 -text "Refresh"; grid .row0.b0c2 -row 0 -column 2 -sticky "ew"
button .row0.b0c3 -text "Sticky";  grid .row0.b0c3 -row 0 -column 3 -sticky "ew"
button .row0.b0c4 -text "Open";    grid .row0.b0c4 -row 0 -column 4 -sticky "ew"

# Row 1
frame .row1
grid .row1 -row 1 -column 0 -columnspan 3 -sticky "ew"
grid columnconfigure .row1 {0 1 2} -weight 1
button .row1.b1c0 -text "clear";   grid .row1.b1c0 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "ew"
button .row1.b1c1 -text "search";  grid .row1.b1c1 -row 0 -column 1 -sticky "ew"
entry  .row1.e1c2 -bg "Azure";     grid .row1.e1c2 -row 0 -column 2 -sticky "nsew"

# Row 2
frame .row2
grid .row2 -row 2 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"
grid columnconfigure .row2 0 -weight 1
listbox .row2.l2 -bg "Beige";     grid .row2.l2 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"

# Row 3
frame .row3
grid .row3 -row 3 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"
grid columnconfigure .row3 0 -weight 1
label .row3.l3 -bg "Azure";       grid .row3.l3 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"

raise .

# Wait forever
set forever 1
vwait forever
```

and here's what it looks like:

[image]

Not sure ... seems like XAML should translated one to one into Tcl/TK?  am i missing something here?

Comment: The grid algorithm are obviously not the same. Your tcl script should look similar if each row had it's own frame.

Comment: #thingamabobs,  I took your suggestion, and updated the question.   your suggestion somewhat fixes it.  can you take another look.

Comment: Just looking at the pictures, I don't understand what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is an abbreviated form of the answer by pico. This takes advantage of the fact that `grid` can put multiple widgets next to each other on the same line (with the same options) on a single line, and the next call to `grid` with the same master widget will default to putting things in the next line after the end of the current contents. You can use explicit coordinates... but it's very long-winded and you don't have to; that's the sort of thing that only a GUI generation tool would do.

The other things to note below:

- It's really worth saving the names of any widgets that you plan to manipulate later. It's probably also worth giving them slightly more mnemonic names than effectively just coordinates; easier to debug if nothing else! You hardly ever need to save the names of frames, or of labels, labelframes or buttons (if you use `-textvariable`). Even entries can often be left alone. Complex widgets often need their name saving, as you frequently want to control them dynamically.
- Listboxes (and entries and text widgets and canvases) need to be connected to their scrollbars as well as *vice versa*. Without that, the scrollbar won't do its tricks (because it won't know how long the content or viewport are).

```
package require Tk

wm title . "MainWindow"
wm geometry . 210x800
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure    . 2 -weight 1 

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
set f [frame .row0 -bg "lightgray"]
grid $f -columnspan 5 -sticky "ew"
button $f.b0c0 -text "Home" -command {puts "Home pressed"}
button $f.b0c1 -text "End" -command {puts "End pressed"}
button $f.b0c2 -text "Refresh" -command {puts "Refresh pressed"}
button $f.b0c3 -text "Sticky" -command {puts "Sticky pressed"}
button $f.b0c4 -text "Open" -command {puts "Open pressed"}
grid $f.b0c0 $f.b0c1 $f.b0c2 $f.b0c3 $f.b0c4

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
set f [frame .row1]
grid $f -columnspan 3 -sticky "ew"
grid columnconfigure $f 2 -weight 1
button $f.b1c0 -text "clear" -command {puts "clear pressed"}
button $f.b1c1 -text "search" -command {puts "search pressed"}
# Remember name of widget for later, when manipulating content
set searchbox [entry $f.e1c2 -bg "Azure"]
grid $f.b1c0 $f.b1c1 $searchbox
grid configure $searchbox -sticky "nsew"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
set f [frame .row2]
grid $f -sticky "nsew"
grid columnconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
# Make sure -yscrollcommand is given to complete linking of listbox and scrollbar
set itemlist [listbox $f.l2 -bg "Beige" -yscroll [list $f.sb set]]
scrollbar $f.sb -orient vertical -command [list $itemlist yview]
grid $itemlist $f.sb -sticky "nsew"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
set f [frame .row3]
grid $f -sticky "sew"
grid columnconfigure $f 0 -weight 1
set modeline [label $f.l3 -bg "Azure" -height 1 -anchor "w"]
grid $modeline -sticky "nsew"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
$modeline configure -text "Hello"

# Fill the listbox with 100 strings
for {set i 1} {$i <= 100} {incr i} {
    $itemlist insert end "String $i"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
package require Tk

wm title . "MainWindow"
wm geometry . 210x800
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure    . 2 -weight 1 

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Row 0
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
frame .row0 -bg "lightgray"  ;# Set the background color to gray
grid .row0 -row 0 -column 0 -columnspan 5 -sticky "ew"
grid columnconfigure .row0 0 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row0 frame
grid columnconfigure .row0 1 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row0 frame
grid columnconfigure .row0 2 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row0 frame
grid columnconfigure .row0 3 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row0 frame
grid columnconfigure .row0 4 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row0 frame
button .row0.b0c0 -text "Home";    grid .row0.b0c0 -row 0 -column 0  ;# Remove sticky option
button .row0.b0c1 -text "End";     grid .row0.b0c1 -row 0 -column 1  ;# Remove sticky option
button .row0.b0c2 -text "Refresh"; grid .row0.b0c2 -row 0 -column 2  ;# Remove sticky option
button .row0.b0c3 -text "Sticky";  grid .row0.b0c3 -row 0 -column 3  ;# Remove sticky option
button .row0.b0c4 -text "Open";    grid .row0.b0c4 -row 0 -column 4  ;# Remove sticky option

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Row 1
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
frame .row1
grid .row1 -row 1 -column 0 -columnspan 3 -sticky "ew"
grid columnconfigure .row1 0 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row1 frame
grid columnconfigure .row1 1 -weight 0  ;# Set column weight for .row1 frame
grid columnconfigure .row1 2 -weight 1  ;# Set column weight for .row1 frame
button .row1.b1c0 -text "clear";   grid .row1.b1c0 -row 0 -column 0  ;# Remove sticky option
button .row1.b1c1 -text "search";  grid .row1.b1c1 -row 0 -column 1  ;# Remove sticky option
entry  .row1.e1c2 -bg "Azure";     grid .row1.e1c2 -row 0 -column 2 -sticky "nsew"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Row 2
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
frame .row2
grid .row2 -row 2 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"
grid columnconfigure .row2 0 -weight 1  ;# Set listbox column weight to 1
grid columnconfigure .row2 1 -weight 0  ;# Set scrollbar column weight to 0
grid rowconfigure .row2 0 -weight 1
listbox .row2.l2 -bg "Beige";       grid .row2.l2 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"
scrollbar .row2.sb -orient vertical -command {.row2.l2 yview}; grid .row2.sb -row 0 -column 1 -sticky "ns"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Row 3
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
frame .row3
grid .row3 -row 3 -column 0 -sticky "sew"  ;# Change sticky property to "s" to anchor row 3 to the bottom
grid columnconfigure .row3 0 -weight 1
label .row3.l3 -bg "Azure" -height 1 -anchor "w"; grid .row3.l3 -row 0 -column 0 -sticky "nsew"  ;# Set fixed height for row 3


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure Content
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
.row3.l3 configure -text "Hello"

# Fill the listbox with 100 strings
for {set i 1} {$i <= 100} {incr i} {
    .row2.l2 insert end "String $i"
}

raise .

# Wait forever
set forever 1
vwait forever
```

Comment: The code can be a bit shorter; column (and row) weights default to zero.